# How can i change my dashboard field after Authentication? laravel-8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I can login and register with laravel-8 after login or register it takes me to the dashboard which is an automated generated page with auth in laravel -8 named dashbord.blde.php but after login I want to go to my index.blade.php page path of this page is resource/views/prducts/index.blade.php. Thanks in advance. :)
here in my web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php` file, for example, you would find the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

You can see that a `$redirectTo` variable exists and has the value of `/home` where users are redirected after they are logged in.

In this case, you should change it to `protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';`

stolen with respect from : https://www.techiediaries.com/laravel-auth-redirection-using-redirectto/

Answer (score 0):

Following the contribution above, you can change the '/home' redirect to '/products/index', and in the web.php declare this route

```
Route::get('/products/index', function(){
    return view('products.index');
})->name('products_index');
```